# Not receiving any data from OpenWeatherMap api android studio

Tags: java, android, api, openweathermap

I don't know where exactly the problem lies, the app crashes anytime I log.i the info from the api. 
This is the code. I don't know whether the code is out dated, I am running the newest version of Android Studio.

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();

            }

            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

            Log.i("Weather content", weatherInfo);

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.i("main", jsonPart.getString("main"));
                Log.i("description", jsonPart.getString("description"));

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
}
```

If you could help me out that would be awesome, I'm quite excited to make my own weather app!

Answer (score 0):

You don't convert a single byte and convert to a char like this:

```
char current = (char) data;
```

Your `result` string will end up with lots of strange characters

Instead you wrap your `InputStreamReader` to a `BufferedReader`, read line by line and collect your `JSON`.

Another easier way is to use `JSONObject` to read your stream:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(
          new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Then change your `AsyncTask` to return `JSONObject` directly

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            return (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(reader);;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply I really appreciate it. I was wondering, do you have a working example? I'm quite new to this field,there's little for me to go on based on my knowledge. I appreciate your work!

Comment: I already provided you a sample code. Are you using "JSONObject" from Java or a library?

Comment: I'm using them from Java to get info from the api. I'm not exactly sure where to put the code / what exactly to replace. Again I am really new to this, sorry. It would help out to know how exactly this code would work.

Comment: Do you use `JSONObject ` from Java or from a library?

Comment: I get my 'JSONObject' from the OpenWeatherMap api. I believe that's a library.

Comment: Try my edited answer, if it's not work, post the full class path of `JSONObject` here :)

Comment: Hey buddy, I got the code to work! partially. When I log the "result" at the  onPostExecute I get "null". This is at least better then last time when it crashed on start up, however I still get no JSON data my way. "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London" this is the api i am using :)

Comment: `{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}` you did not specify API key. You need to register the API key with the site and include it with your query

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, it passed my head. However the app seems to crash even with a working api link. I think the problem lies in the doInBackground code. the working api link would be  https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=10eab024641bd90dd887fb79da9fd43f

Comment: The correct one: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=5d8fea5f1c9cdfe8af473504e5f9002a

Comment: How's your code look like now? Could you edit it in your question so I can follow

Comment: Hey happy to tell you I figured out a method that works for! Thank you for the help!